# How to load specific data in div from select create from JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I try to load values for user in div "sel_user" from select populate from json.

hi guys am trying to load data in div "sel_user" from JSON file. This data load when i select a option from populate select create from this JSON also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--funcion para cargar el select box desde el json-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('checkin.php', function(data) {
                var items = '';
                var len = data.length;
                var name = data[0]['name'];
                var tiempo = data[0]['tiempo'];
                $.each(data, function(name, value) {
                    items += "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</option>";
                });
                $("#clients").html(items);
                $("#sel_user").append("<div>" + name + "</div>");
                $("#sel_user").append("<div>" + tiempo + "</div>");
                $("#sel_user").append("<div>" + name + "</div>");
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>


    <select id="clients">
        <option value="0">-- choose user --</option>
    </select>

    <div>-- info user --</div>
    <div id="sel_user"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

my JSON is

```
"usuarios": [
    {
        "codigo": "U001",
        "name": "EDWAR TOBAR",
        "cargo": "",`enter code here`
        "telefono": "",
        "email": "",
        "telefono1": "3137532371",
        "abonados": 8,
        "tiempo": "2017-04-28T22:03:18.000Z",
        "evento": "",
        "devento": ""
    },
    {
        "codigo": "U002",
        "name": "JHON HENRY CARVAJAL",
        "cargo": "",
        "telefono": "",
        "email": "",
        "telefono1": "3136706365",
        "abonados": 8,
        "tiempo": "2017-04-28T22:03:18.000Z",
        "evento": "",
        "devento": ""
    },
    {
        "codigo": "U006",
        "name": "CLAVE DE COACCION",
        "cargo": "",
        "telefono": "",
        "email": "",
        "telefono1": "",
        "abonados": 8,
        "tiempo": "2017-04-28T22:03:18.000Z",
        "evento": "",
        "devento": ""
    },
    {
        "codigo": "U003",
        "name": "JAVIER QUI ONEZ",
        "cargo": "",
        "telefono": "",
        "email": "",
        "telefono1": "3177364180",
        "abonados": 8,
        "tiempo": "2017-04-28T22:03:38.000Z",
        "evento": "",
        "devento": ""
    }
]
```

}

The select id="clients" works fine. Charge the users for my JSON when the jquery function. But, when i select one user the data for user don charge in div id="sel_user". Please, help me.

Comment: You need to store the received data, then populate the `div` in the `<select>`'s `onchange` handler.

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p7e2wvps/

Comment: Thank you man! work for me!